# Nodejs - How to route by name in url with express and mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an Express 4 server with CRUD routes for authors:

```
    router.get('/authors', AuthorsController.index);
    router.post('/authors', AuthorsController.store);
    router.get('/authors/:name', AuthorsController.show);
    router.put('/authors/:name', AuthorsController.update);
    router.delete('/authors/:name', AuthorsController.remove);
```

Most tutorials I find will have the routes be `/authors/:id` and then do `Author.findById(req.params.id)`. I'd instead like it to be the authors name so there are human readable URLs, like: `/authors/jk-rowling`.

Do I need to store the hyphenated string on the Authors model, what's the best way to achieve this with express and Mongoosejs?

My authors controller currently looks like this:

```
const AuthorsController = {
  async index(req, res){
    const authors = await Author.find().populate('books');
    res.send(authors);
  }
};
```

(I'm using express-async-errors package for the async-await functionality with express)

What's the best way to establish routes with human readable URLs for a CRUD REST API with Express and Mongoose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index **name** field and in your views, find by name (assuming name is attribute of Author)

This requires no change in terms of db model. You can search via both id or name if needed.

For example

```
 router.get('/authors/:name', AuthorsController.show);
```

will have below view

```
const AuthorsController = {
  async show(req, res){
    const authors = await Author.find({'name':req.params.name}).populate('books');
    res.send(authors);
  }
};
```

As you mentioned in problem, you will have to generate **slug** for name like one containing hyphens in place of spaces or other special characters which will be stored in model as well.

Comment: Hey welcome Shirish. Thanks for the reply! Are you able to provide a code sample in this answer for how it would potentially work?

Comment: Added example to my response above